# Custom Options Price Value

Tags: price, custom-options

How do I display Custom Options Price Total value? I created a Custom Options with price difference of minus 100 dollars, I used negative sing (-)
and then 100 dollar. Cheaper because I have "used or return product" sometimes. Custom Options is set at Title > Condition > input type > check-box > Price -$100. The price on Front end shows in Custom Options area -$100 - how do I go about displaying a price total Value? in this case it would be...

spacial Price $300
Custom Options -$100

Value to display $200

Thank you

Comment: This is what exactly you are looking for https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html

Answer (score 2):

You need absolute pricing - if you search the Magentocommerce forums you will find it. We use an embedded extension which includes it but it is part of a complete pricing solution so wouldn't work for you.

Comment: We asaking some people if they will let us have the code as an extension, we'll let you know.

Comment: So we asked some consultants if they would assist and they agreed to provide a drop-in extension to fix the issue for you - however this happened - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30439/how-to-add-currency-suffix-to-url-links - sorry