# How to add currency suffix to URL links?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I need to add a currency suffix to url links for the products.
For example: When switching currency to CAD or USD in ANY Magento store. There is NO code in the URL links which states the currency.

```
www.example.com/pencils.html
```

I need is this: When switching currency to USD 
link should look like:

```
www.example.com/pencils.html?currency=usd
```

When switching currency to CAD
link should look like:

```
www.example.com/pencils.html?currency=cad
```

Comment: What could be a solution? I need ANY kind of suffix at the end of the url's that disinuishes url links between CAD and USD.

Comment: Try adding ?currency=USD or GBP or any other currency that your website support and see if it converts.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out for the past week or so. Cant find the solution. Other sites that run other eCommerce platforms have this code fully working.

Comment: Serpyte, gentleman below mentioned the solution to our problem. How did it work in your case ?

Comment: I just realized the extension is no longer available. It got deleted. :(

Comment: Do you think, I will be able to receive the file ? I downloaded it at first, but I have no idea where it was saved on the computer. If there is no other way of getting the file, I will to try searching, hopefully I can retrieve it.
I still really appreciate the fact, they posted the file in the beginning.

Comment: Please ask if its possible to pass it on. If not, let me know who to contact ? (link to their website). Many thanks!

Comment: Serpyte, by installing this plug in, how will the links look like when switching between CAD,USD,GBP,EURO ?

Comment: Hello,
I have moved the files from extension folder through FileZilla (ftp) and for some reason it doesn't switch between the prices. I've been adding these suffixes as ?currency=cad and ?currency=usd at the end of the url and there are no changes.  I have tried reindexing and refreshing cache in the admin panel of magento as well as cleared cash in browser.

Comment: I have noticed the extension works on plane magento website with sample data. On a real website with template the code is not working. I really like how it work on sample website. Does what its supposed to do. Is there anything I can do to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe there is an alternative code, other than ?currency=CAD ?

Comment: Could you please provide the website/contact information of the person/company I can reach to debug this issue. I.E. the company that created this extension.

Comment: Ok, thank anyways. I know only very basic of Magento, therefore I need to hire somebody who can set this module up for me. Someone reputable would be great.

Comment: Awesome, send me your direct contact info/website. I will write you via contacts page.

Comment: I have no idea, I am questioning myself. Your website is plain wordpress. I dont see contact us button or telephone to call.

Comment: I was notified this extension conflicts with my custom template. Looks like there should be some code editing.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the  solution.... which default magento currency change url
Copy **app>code>Core>Mage>Directory>Helper>Url.php**

to   **app>local>Core>Mage>Directory>Helper>Url.php**

and change the code of function

```
public function getSwitchCurrencyUrl($params = array())
{
    $params = is_array($params) ? $params : array();


    if ($this->_getRequest()->getAlias('rewrite_request_path')) {
        $url = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $this->_getRequest()->getAlias('rewrite_request_path');
    }
    else {
        $url = $this->getCurrentUrl();
    }
     $params[Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($url);
    if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?')){
    $CurrentUrl=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'&_currency='   .$params['currency'];
    }else{
        $CurrentUrl=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?_currency='   .$params['currency'];
    }
    return $CurrentUrl;
    //return $this->_getUrl('directory/currency/switch', $params);

}
```

Then goto 
copy `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php`

to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php`

function `setRouteParams`  add  below code

```
        if(!is_null($this->getRequest()->getParam('_currency'))):
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('_currency')==Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()){

        }else{
            Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($this->getRequest()->getParam('_currency'));
        }
endif;
```

before code `unset($data['_store_to_url']);`
 Modify function setRouteParams

```
public function setRouteParams(array $data, $unsetOldParams = true)
{
    if (isset($data['_type'])) {
        $this->setType($data['_type']);
        unset($data['_type']);
    }

    if (isset($data['_store'])) {
        $this->setStore($data['_store']);
        unset($data['_store']);
    }

    if (isset($data['_forced_secure'])) {
        $this->setSecure((bool)$data['_forced_secure']);
        $this->setSecureIsForced(true);
        unset($data['_forced_secure']);
    } elseif (isset($data['_secure'])) {
        $this->setSecure((bool)$data['_secure']);
        unset($data['_secure']);
    }

    if (isset($data['_absolute'])) {
        unset($data['_absolute']);
    }

    if ($unsetOldParams) {
        $this->unsetData('route_params');
    }

    $this->setUseUrlCache(true);
    if (isset($data['_current'])) {
        if (is_array($data['_current'])) {
            foreach ($data['_current'] as $key) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $data) || !$this->getRequest()->getUserParam($key)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $data[$key] = $this->getRequest()->getUserParam($key);
            }
        } elseif ($data['_current']) {
            foreach ($this->getRequest()->getUserParams() as $key => $value) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $data) || $this->getRouteParam($key)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $data[$key] = $value;
            }
            foreach ($this->getRequest()->getQuery() as $key => $value) {
                $this->setQueryParam($key, $value);
            }
            $this->setUseUrlCache(false);
        }
        unset($data['_current']);
    }

    if (isset($data['_use_rewrite'])) {
        unset($data['_use_rewrite']);
    }

    if (isset($data['_store_to_url']) && (bool)$data['_store_to_url'] === true) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_STORE_IN_URL, $this->getStore())
            && !Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()
        ) {
            $this->setQueryParam('___store', $this->getStore()->getCode());
        }
    }

    /* add by amit bera */
if(!is_null($this->getRequest()->getParam('_currency'))):
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('_currency')==Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()){

    }else{
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($this->getRequest()->getParam('_currency'));
    }
endif;
/* end by amit bera */


    unset($data['_store_to_url']);

    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $this->setRouteParam($k, $v);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Let me know ,if you have any issue.

Comment: Amit, could you please provide a link of Magento store, to see  how this correction functions ?

Comment: Sorry, i do not provide you link,i have test on my local system  and it is working

Comment: O, no problem.
Just to clarify, you have mentioned the following: Then goto copy app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

function setRouteParams add below code

I did not understand this part, could you please clarify.

Comment: yes,just before unset($data['_store_to_url']);

Comment: Sorry, but I just got lost :(

Comment: where???,which magento version using???

Comment: I am using 1.7.2. I am lost in the whole process.

Comment: where r u stack??

Comment: I dont understand what to do here:
Then goto copy app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

function setRouteParams add below code

Comment: check code , i have put full function code...

Comment: I just checked. I dont have the following directory
app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

It ends here:app/code/local/Mage/

Comment: What to do when I dont have this full directory ? app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

Comment: have you file/dir app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php ??

Comment: Yes I have added the code to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

But then you mention, something about this directory app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php

I am not able to find such directory in my FileManager

Comment: just copy Url.php from app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/ to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?')){
$CurrentUrl=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'&_currency='   .$params['currency'];
}else{
    $CurrentUrl=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?_currency='   .$params['currency'];
}
return $CurrentUrl;
```

with

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?')){
        $url_arr = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        $query = $url_arr['query'];
        $url = str_replace(array($query,'?'), '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        $CurrentUrl=$url.'?currency='   .$params['currency'];
    }else{
        $CurrentUrl=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?currency='   .$params['currency'];
    }
    return $CurrentUrl;
```

Working perfect for me.