# Magento 1.9 - Append current url with parameters

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, parameter

I want to add currency param with current url like

> www.example.com

to

> www.example.com/?currency=USD

Want to load website with param by default because default currency is USD.
I found this below link but its working with currency switch.
[How to add currency suffix to URL links?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30439/how-to-add-currency-suffix-to-url-links/224941#224941)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to set the default Display currency when website will load then you can set **Default Display Currency**  for each website from

```
System->Configuration->General->currency setup ->currency options->Default Display Currency.
```

The currency you select there that will display by default.

Comment: I want url like www.example.com/?currency=USD instead of example.com.

Comment: if u want to set for all pages then set base url  like that or if you want for specific page you can try to modify url by using controller_action_predispatch event.